# Searching Annotations in MapView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, annotations, mkmapview

I followed a  [how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/) about searching `annotations` in `mapView`
and its searching around the world with `MKLocalSearch`.

However, I don't want to to search with `MKLocalSearch` but search my own `annotations` i added myself like these for example:

```
let LitzmanLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.100668,34.775192)
        // Drop a pin
        let Litzman = MKPointAnnotation()
        Litzman.coordinate = LitzmanLocation
        Litzman.title = "Litzman Bar"
        Litzman.subtitle = "נמל תל אביב 18,תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Litzman)

        let ShalvataLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.101145,34.775163)
        // Drop a pin
        let Shalvata = MKPointAnnotation()
        Shalvata.coordinate = ShalvataLocation
        Shalvata.title = "Shalvata"
        Shalvata.subtitle = "האנגר 28,נמל תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Shalvata)


        let MarkidLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.074961,34.781679)
        // Drop a pin
        let Markid = MKPointAnnotation()
        Markid.coordinate = MarkidLocation
        Markid.title = "Markid"
        Markid.subtitle = "אבן גבירול 30,תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Markid)
```

Here is my Code:

## **MapViewController.Swift:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

protocol HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil

    var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil

    @IBAction func MapSearchController(sender: AnyObject) {
        resultSearchController!.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController!.searchBar.delegate = self
        presentViewController(resultSearchController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.resultSearchController!.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.resultSearchController!.searchBar.placeholder = "חפש ברים"
        self.resultSearchController!.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.resultSearchController!.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
        resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable

        locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView

        locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
}
}
}

extension MapViewController: HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
        // cache the pin
        selectedPin = placemark
        // clear existing pins
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
        annotation.title = placemark.name
        if let city = placemark.locality,
            let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
            annotation.subtitle = "(city) (state)"
        }
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

## **LocalSearchTable.Swift:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {

    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil

    var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil

    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }

    }

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapSearchCell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem)
        return cell
    }
}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(selectedItem)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What? You have some data source to search on it? What do you mean by "searching annotations" ?

Comment: I have like 100 annotation in my mapView and its annoying to tap one by one to find the one im looking for so i dont know how really but i want to create some sort of search . You understand now?

Comment: Filter the annotations by the title and create a search function

Comment: No, how your annotation get into the map? You have some data source and populate maps with annotations? Why u cannot search through that data source and want to search through annotations?

Comment: I will be able to post my code in a few hours

Comment: Updated the code @Kuba

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620002/map-annotations-search More Updated Question.

Answer (score 2):

you just  refer to this link 
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/02/14/mapkit-demo-swift-annotation-custom-annotation-custom-annotation-with-button-search-showing-directions-apple-maps-ios/

you will understand the following topics

- Show Annotation in Maps.
- Show Custom Annotation in Maps.
- Show Custom Annotation with Custom Button in Maps.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Example project: https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO40539590

---

Ok, so for the beginning I will suggest you separate data from your controller code. I choose `json` format as most universal one. So:

```
[
   {
      "title":"Litzman Bar",
      "subtitle":"נמל תל אביב 18,תל אביב",
      "coordinates":{
         "lat":32.100668,
         "lon":34.775192
      }
   },
   {
      "title":"Shalvata",
      "subtitle":"האנגר 28,נמל תל אביב",
      "coordinates":{
         "lat":32.101145,
         "lon":34.775163
      }
   },
   {
      "title":"Markid",
      "subtitle":"אבן גבירול 30,תל אביב",
      "coordinates":{
         "lat":32.074961,
         "lon":34.781679
      }
   }
]
```

This is basically your database.

Now let's parse it into an `Array` to use inside your `ViewConttroller`. Again I will suggest you split it into Model objects like `Location` and `Coordinate`. Let's have a look in one class of it as example:

```
class Location: NSObject {

    var title : String = String()
    var subtitle : String = String()
    var coordinates : Coordinate = Coordinate()

    public class func locationFromDictionary(_ dictionary : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> Location {
        let location : Location = Location()
        location.title = dictionary["title"] as! String
        location.subtitle = dictionary["subtitle"] as! String
        location.coordinates = Coordinate.coordinateFromDictionary(dictionary["coordinates"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
        return location;
    }
}
```

I will not paste the code for parsing `json` file to this objects, because that's what is not this question is about. You will find in into repository.

And now let's focus on question.

**I will recommend you not to search annotations, but search your data model and redraw annotations when needed**

In order to do that (i will use `UISearchBar` for it):

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.displayArray = self.locationsDatabase.filter() {
        return $0.title.contains("i")
    }
```

Then when you ovverride a setter like this:

```
var displayArray : Array<Location> = [] {
    didSet {
        self.mapView .removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
        for location in displayArray {
            let coords : Coordinate = location.coordinates
            let point = MKPointAnnotation()
            point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(coords.latitude),CLLocationDegrees(coords.longitude))
            point.title = location.title
            point.subtitle = location.subtitle
            mapView.addAnnotation(point)
        }
    }
}
```

You can redraw your annotations. The edge cases like empty search field, case sensivity, dismissing keyboard I leave to you. But hope you will get the general idea. You may think that it's overengineered but having objects as a separate classes and universal format as an data input may benefit in the future.

Full project: https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO40539590

Comment: Hey man thanks for answering! as i said i have a more updated question with what code i have right now, i'v just edited the question and made it the same as the new question.Secondly I need to `search` for `annotation`s and not draw new ones or use `MKLocalSearch`  because the `mapView` is showing the user the locations of Restaurants nearby so i need to search the `annotations` and when i select a result it will `zoom` and `center` on the correct `annotation`. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: **Filter the annotations by the Title

Comment: Yes, still I recommend you to get this restaurant into an `Array` and search through this array and update the map when needed. If u insist to search through displayed annotations mapView has an array `annotations` that displayed all annotations. But searching them has a lot of downsides, like - what will happen if user search once and want to search again? You will hide annotations and cannot search again there. You have to get this data to display from somewhere - search this stack instead of annotations.

Comment: If i want to search again i will just type tap the result i want and it will zoom and center on the result i want it to - at least thats what im wishing to do, and if i dont wanna search again i will just click on another tab i have or will zoom out and choose manually