# Map Annotations Search

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, search, mkmapview

I followed a  [how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/) about searching `annotations` in `mapView`
and its searching around the world with `MKLocalSearch`.

However, I don't want to to search with `MKLocalSearch` but search my own `annotations` i added myself like these for example:

```
let LitzmanLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.100668,34.775192)
        // Drop a pin
        let Litzman = MKPointAnnotation()
        Litzman.coordinate = LitzmanLocation
        Litzman.title = "Litzman Bar"
        Litzman.subtitle = "נמל תל אביב 18,תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Litzman)

        let ShalvataLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.101145,34.775163)
        // Drop a pin
        let Shalvata = MKPointAnnotation()
        Shalvata.coordinate = ShalvataLocation
        Shalvata.title = "Shalvata"
        Shalvata.subtitle = "האנגר 28,נמל תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Shalvata)


        let MarkidLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.074961,34.781679)
        // Drop a pin
        let Markid = MKPointAnnotation()
        Markid.coordinate = MarkidLocation
        Markid.title = "Markid"
        Markid.subtitle = "אבן גבירול 30,תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Markid)
```

Here is my Code:

## **MapViewController.Swift:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

protocol HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil

    var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil

    @IBAction func MapSearchController(sender: AnyObject) {
        resultSearchController!.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController!.searchBar.delegate = self
        presentViewController(resultSearchController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.resultSearchController!.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.resultSearchController!.searchBar.placeholder = "חפש ברים"
        self.resultSearchController!.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.resultSearchController!.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
        resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable

        locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView

        locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
}
}
}

extension MapViewController: HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
        // cache the pin
        selectedPin = placemark
        // clear existing pins
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
        annotation.title = placemark.name
        if let city = placemark.locality,
            let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
            annotation.subtitle = "(city) (state)"
        }
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

## **LocalSearchTable.Swift:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {

    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil

    var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil

    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }

    }

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapSearchCell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem)
        return cell
    }
}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(selectedItem)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching Annotations in MapView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539590/searching-annotations-in-mapview)

Comment: Yes i tried to link you to here

Comment: Yes i know, didn't saw it before sorry.

Comment: I wish i knew how to do it my own really but no one has a tutorial like this or anything close to what i want to do but i see it in a lot of professional apps like "HotPoint" in their maps

Comment: @Kuba do you know a solution for what i want?

Comment: @NewbieQuestions could you please explain it a bit more that what you want to achieve,  ("I don't want to to search with MKLocalSearch but search my own annotations i added ")

Comment: You see how i manually created 3 `annotations` with `let Litzman` etc? .... i want to create a `search` that will only `search` these manually created `annotations`...and won't drop new `annotations` and `search` around the world.You understand now?

Comment: @ZaidPathan ^^^^^

Answer (score 1):

So create an array of your annotation objects and save it in an instance variable. Let's call it `annotationsArray`.

Then you can design a UI that lets the user enter search terms. Say you only search on Title. Then you could use:

```
let titleMatches = annotationsArray.filter{$0.title == titleToMatch}
```

And then display the set of filtered annotations to the map with the `addAnnotations()` function. (Note the plural)

Comment: Hey,Thanks for answering. Can you please go into more details with the codes cause I'm absolutely new to swift and i don't understand quite well .

Comment: Not sure how I can go into more detail without writing your app for you. Do you know how to create an array? Do you know how to use the filter function on an array? Do you know how to collect an input string from the users? I suggest you research each of those things in turn and try to put them together into a feature.

Comment: Do what ever you can anything will be helpfull